# ExecStartPost in supervisor?

Tags: supervisord, systemd

I am moving from systemd to supervisord.

in systemd service you can write:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
ExecStart=mycommand
ExecStartPost=anothercommand
```

I want to write `ExecStartPost` in supervisor

```
[program:myservice]
command=thesamecommand
???command_after=??
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
```

Comment: I am moving back to Systemd